# Java...getting first number of each set of 13

Tags: java, mysql

I am trying to make a Java program that will help me update a database.

I have this code

```
for(int i = 1; i < 3095; i++)
    if((i-1)%13==0)
         System.out.println();
     System.out.println("INSERT INTO categories ('"+i+"' , '"+(i+13)+'");
```

Basically I need to find a way to record the first number of each set of 13 and put it into the `System.out.println` command.  How can I get the original `i+13` to work?

I am looking for the finished program to output something like this:

```
INSERT INTO categories (categories_id, parent_id) VALUES ('1', '1')
INSERT INTO categories (categories_id, parent_id) VALUES ('2', '1')
INSERT INTO categories (categories_id, parent_id) VALUES ('3', '1')....


INSERT INTO categories (categories_id, parent_id) VALUES ('14', '14')
INSERT INTO categories (categories_id, parent_id) VALUES ('15', '14')
INSERT INTO categories (categories_id, parent_id) VALUES ('16', '14')....etc
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's your code to do what you want and with some more appropriate curly braces:

```
    for (int i = 1; i < 3095; i++) {
        if ((i-1) % 13 == 0) {
            System.out.println();
        }
        System.out.println("INSERT INTO categories (categories_id, parent_id) " +
                           "VALUES ('" + i + "' , '" + (i - ((i-1) % 13)) + "')");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming  `i` is an `int`, thanks to truncating integer division, `i/13*13 + 1` will be 1 for `i` = 0, 1, 3, .., 12, then skips to 14 for i = 13, 14, 15, ..., 25, then skips to 27, ...

If you want something that's 1 for 1,2,3,..13 and then skips to 14 on 14, use `(i-1)/13*13 + 1`.

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding of what you want to do -> You can do something like this:

```
int i, j;
    for(i = 1; i < 3095; i+=13) {
        for(j=i; j<i+13; j++)
            System.out.println("INSERT INTO categories ('" + j + "' , '" + i + "\')");
        System.out.println();
        }
    }
```

The output is something like this:

```
INSERT INTO categories ('1' , '1') .... INSERT INTO categories ('13' , '1')
INSERT INTO categories ('14' , '14') ... INSERT INTO categories ('26' , '14') 
INSERT INTO categories ('27' , '27') ... INSERT INTO categories ('39' , '27')
```

and so on...

Answer (score 0):

Unsure, but thought of

```
SET @num = 0;
INSERT INTO categories (categories_id, parent_id)
    SELECT @num := @num + 1, (@num DIV 13) * 13 + 1
    WHERE @num < 3095;
```

Maybe `FROM DUAL`.